# How to pass the Value of particular field of parent View to Child View in MVC4?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I have to pass the Id (which is select from a particular field) from Parent View to Child View. I will explain  my issue clearly.

**Parent View**

[image: Parent View]

In my parent view I have two fields. CustomerName and ContactPerson. Both are dropdowns.Both are cascading dropdown. If i select a CustomerName the CustomerName related ContactPerson will automatically load  in ContactPerson dropdown.

Suppose if the ContactPerson name is not in the list means i will click that + button which is near to ContactPerson. It will open one pop window.The pop-window is below

**Pop-up Window (Child View)**

[image]

Now all are working fine. Now i have one new issue. That is if i select the CustomerName and then select the ContactPerson but the contactperson name is not in the list. so  i click the + button it will open the pop-up window at the same time it have to pass the ID from parent view( CustomerID which i select in the parent view CustomerName dropdown)  to the CustomerName Field (Which is in pop-up window child view ). How i do this . Any one help me to resolve this issue. I tried to explain my issue as per my leve best Any one understand my issue give some solution or Suggestion to this problem.

**My View Code**

Parent view dropdownlist

```
@Html.Label("Customer Name", new { @class = "control-label" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerID, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a Customer", new { @class = "form-control required", type = "text" })
```

Modal form view

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <span style="color: #f00">*</span>
    @Html.Label("Contact Person", new { @class = "control-label" })<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="modal-opener" style="float: right; Width: 28px; height: 28px; ">+</a>
    <div id="dialog-modal" title="Add New Contact Person" style="display:none">
        <div class="box-body">
            @Html.Label("Customer Name")
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerID, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a Customer", new { @class = "form-control required", type = "text", id = "CustomerName" })

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactPerson)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ContactPerson, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContactPerson)

            ....

            <div class="box-footer">
                <input id="Button1" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Save" onclick="SaveContact()" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My J-query Code**

```
$(function () {
    $("#modal-opener").click(function () {
        debugger
        $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");
    });
    ....
})
```

Advance Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need a dropdownlist for the customer name in the modal? Surely you want that to be the the value of the customer name from the main view? (in which case you should be passing the CustomerId from the main view and just displaying the customer name so its not editable)

Comment: No Stephen i dont want that field as dropdown(CustomerName which is in pop-up window). I am going to keep that field as textbox. CustomerID in the sense the Customer Name Field in the parent view. It is dropdown.

Comment: Actually it should be just a `<div>` to display the customer name because you dont need to submit that (style it to look like a textbox if you want). You need a hidden input for the `CustomerID` property value. What is the html of the customer name dropdownlist in the main view (in particular what is its `id` attribute)

Comment: wait i will post my parent view dropdwon coding

Comment: ok wait i have a check stephen

Comment: Stephen all the view code  and jquery code in same view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112576/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-susan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your currently generating html with duplicate `id` attributes for the `CustomerID` from both modals which is invalid html, so first you need to either change one or other of the property names in your models or override the default `id` attribute in one or other of the form controls in the view.

The next issue is that you should not be generating a dropdownlist for the `CustomerID` in the pop-up form (since its already been selected in the main view), but instead add a hidden input for the selected `CustomerID` (so it can be posted to the controller) and `<div>` element for the selected customer name (which you can then style to look like a textbox).

Change the child (pop-up) view code to

```
<div class="box-body">
    <div>Customer Name</div> // you don't have a control so a label is not appropriate
    <div id="customername"></div> // style this to look like a textbox
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CustomerID, new { id = "customer" }) // add hidden input

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactPerson)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ContactPerson, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContactPerson)

    .... // other controls
```

Note the `id` attribute given to the hidden input so its not a duplicate

Then modify your script for opening the model to

```
$("#modal-opener").click(function () {
    // set the value of the hidden input
    $('#customer').val($('#CustomerID').val());
    // set the value of the customer name
    $('#customername').text($('#CustomerID option:selected').text());
    // display the dialog
    $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");
});
```

Side note: you should check you html for other potential duplicate `id` attributes (e.g. both the parent and child views appear to have form controls for an `Email` property) and change them as required

Comment: Stephen i tried as per you said vut when i click the + button after selecting the Customer Name in Parent view it doesn't open the popwindow

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser console? (and for your interest refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Yy78S3) for something similar (click on the edit link to see how the values are passed to the modal)

Comment: I checked in console and also i checked with debugger. first of all it didnt hit this line $("#modal-opener").click(function ()  when i click the + button.

Comment: But that's your code - all I did was add the 2 lines of code to set the value of the inputs (was it never working in the first place?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112601/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-susan).